# Is there such a tool for testing

Tags: testing

Say one has a structural codebase where lots of the code is in GUI control events and has no tests. So such code, to my knowledge is not suitable for unit testing
Is there a tool that can test each routine automatically replacing references to code elements
external to the routine (be they functions, variables or GUI controls) with appropriate mocks(?) and  record the results in a database for later comparison after code changes? 
So the testing program would have the duty of writing, running and reporting tests with minimal intervention?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't specify a language or development environment, so I am going to provide a few different options below.  You will have to review them and see which one fits your situation and existing tools if needed.

[Selenium](http://seleniumhq.org/)

[Ivonna](http://sm-art.biz/Ivonna.aspx) which requires Typemock Isolator

Microsoft Team System Web Test 2008

[Visual Studio Test Profession 2010](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/en-us/products/2010-editions/test-professional)

HP QuickTest Professional (Link didn't work you will need to copy paste)
'https://h10078.www1.hp.com/cda/hpms/display/main/hpms_content.jsp?zn=bto&cp=1-11-127-24^1352_4000_100__

[Watin](http://watin.sourceforge.net/)

[Watij](http://watij.com/)

[Push To Test](http://www.pushtotest.com/)

Comment: Most of those options are system level tools that exercise the entire webapp; they don't test the control events in isolation, as specified in the question.

Comment: Thanks, I voted up the answer as it provides useful information but as gareth_bowles says I think these tools don't provide the type of functionality I was asking for. I think what I want is a tool that would create by itself a baseline record of an applications behaviour and then report changes to this behaviour as the application is developed. I just wonder if such a tool exists for any language/IDE. A lazy coder's tester I suppose

Comment: @Gareth Most? So some do? So my statement about kjack having to review them to see which one fits his situation and existing tools is valid.

@kjack you just changed your question with that comment. I answered your question as you presented it and I know Ivonna and Typemock Isolator combined will do what you requested in your question, I provided others that  I think may do what you asked for. 

Wanting to record behavior and monitor it over time is profiling and not testing.  There are profiling tools for every popular language. If you ask a new question about profiling you will get answers.

Comment: Ok thanks CG (sorry can't bring myself to use your full username!)
I guess you answered the question as originally framed